# Export Telerik GridView to excel with borders

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, export, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik radGridView1 and i am exporting it to excel, but no borders are shown in the excel file. So how to export it with borders. I am exporting in this way...

```
ExportToExcelML export = new ExportToExcelML(this.radGridView1);
export.ExportVisualSettings = true;
export.RunExport(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the follwoing properties of your rad grid for border before export

```
this.radGridView1.GridLines = Both;
this.radGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
ExportToExcelML export = new ExportToExcelML(this.radGridView1);
export.ExportVisualSettings = true;
export.RunExport(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is giving me an error line for GridLines and BorderStyle. Is there anything i need to add?

Comment: You can set these properties in aspx page itself.

Comment: i am running a Windows Application

Answer (score 0):

The `ExcelCellFormatting` event might help you:

It gives an access to a single cell’s SingleStyleElement that allows you to make additional formatting (adding border, setting alignment, text font, colours, changing cell value, etc.) for every excel cell related to the exported RadGridView:

```
void exporter_ExcelCellFormatting(object sender,Telerik.WinControls.UI.Export.ExcelML.ExcelCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.GridRowInfoType == typeof(GridViewTableHeaderRowInfo))
    {
        BorderStyles border = new BorderStyles();
        border.Color = Color.Black;
        border.Weight = 2;
        border.LineStyle = LineStyle.Continuous;
        border.PositionType = PositionType.Bottom;
        e.ExcelStyleElement.Borders.Add(border);
    }
    else if (e.GridRowIndex == 2 && e.GridColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        e.ExcelStyleElement.InteriorStyle.Color = Color.Yellow;
        e.ExcelStyleElement.AlignmentElement.WrapText = true;
    }
}
```

Click [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-exporting-data-export-to-excel-via-excelml-format.html) for more information.